# In ADS-C-agreement, what is a reporting plan?

Tags: rules-of-the-air

ADS-C agreement. A reporting plan which establishes the conditions of ADS-C data reporting (i.e. data required by the air traffic services unit and frequency of ADS-C reports which have to be agreed to prior to using ADS-C in the provision of air traffic services).

I can't understand "reporting plan".

What is a reporting plan?

Is it like a flight plan?

Is it a paper?

Is it an app?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of your terminology, but you appear to be describing what the [Global Operational Data Link Document (GOLD)](https://www.icao.int/APAC/Documents/edocs/GOLD_2Edition.pdf) describes as ADS-C contracts. ADS-C contracts specify the type of reports required (periodic or event based) and the data to be included in each type of report.

From the GOLD:

> **4.5.2 ADS contracts**
>
> 4.5.2.1 In airspace where procedural separation is being applied, the ATSU should establish the following:
>
> a) ADS periodic contract at an interval appropriate to the airspace
> requirements; and
>
> b) ADS event contract for the following events:
>
> 1. Waypoint change event;
> 2. Lateral deviation event;
> 3. Level range deviation event; and
> 4. Vertical rate change event of negative 5000 feet per minute
>    (descent rate).

The contracts are established by the ATSU and sent to the aircraft after login. The "reporting plan" is that the aircraft will provide the reports as specified by the contracts.

Comment: Thank you. for full description.